# WordPress and VueJS routing problem

Tags: routing

I am testing the integration of a VueJS app in WordPress. 
It actually works (no styles yet).

BUT

If I access a URL like `https://example.com/my-vue-route/about`, the `.htaccess` URL rewriting redirects any incoming HTTPS request to the `index.php` of WordPress. So I actually never land on `/my-vue-route/about` but on the `/about` page, as WordPress thinks I made a typo.

Is it somehow possible to keep the vue routes out of this URL rewriting?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please add add the following line to it to prevent the default behavior for your custom route.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-vue-route/(.+)
```

Like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-vue-route/(.+)
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```