# Wordpress as backend for SPA - problem of 404 page for custom routing

Tags: 404-error, rest-api, front-end

I'm going to use wordpress as backend rest api and vue.js (it doesn't matter what framework) as frontend part. I have some custom route on frontend side, e.g. "/custom". Actually it works on my frontend part, but wordpress doesn't know about this route, so I have actually ok page with 404 status code. Is there ok way to solve this? Of course I can just force 200 for any page on wordpress side, but I hope sync solution exists

Comment: How did you add the route? What’s the code?

Comment: It is happening inside frontend framework. For example, for vue.js it may be vue-router.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress and VueJS routing problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334342/wordpress-and-vuejs-routing-problem)